# When I use kapt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.1.4' in my project,i have a problem that is DataBinderMapperImpl() do not find class

Tags: android, kotlin

I use Google databing library in my Android project. I wrote one module with  Kotlin language and another module in Java language.

When i use kapt `com.android.databinding:compiler:3.1.4` in my project, I found an error that is `DataBinderMapperImpl()` do not find class, but use kapt `com.android.databinding:compiler:3.0.1` do not have above-mentioned error. Why is that?